# phpeclipse: jump to function definition?

Tags: php, eclipse, function, definition

From zend's IDE I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> click on a function name opens the corresponding source file and jumps to the functions definition

Is there anything similar in eclipse especially phpeclipse OR CDT?
I'm not sure if its just a `window->preferences` setting I don't see OR some kind of source code indexing I may have disabled which also don't find in the settings (if available)

Anyone knows the right settings?
I'm using eclipse 3.4.1 with pdt 2.0.0.v20081229.

Answer (score 11):

Using Juno and PDT (PHP Development Tools) you can add this useful feature to a project in this way:

> right click on the project -> Configure -> Add PHP Support.

Comment: Unbeliefable! If upgrading from an older PHPEclipse to Mars with PHP Development Tools ... how can they hide such an important feature so well... Still a helpful answer in 2015, thanks :)

Comment: An answer "back to the future" :D ... thanks for the vote up!

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+Left click usually works in Eclipse as well, although it's horribly slow to react. For that reason I usually use F3 after moving the caret to the function name.

The thing with Ctrl+Click can be found in the preferences in "General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking". It can be turned off, there. But this function apparently required support from the respective editor/parser to be available at all.

The F3 key is bound to "Open Declaration" here. If that's not the case this mapping can be manually added, otherwise it may be that Eclipse is just not able to do that with PHP.

Comment: I had it break on me in 3.4 at some point. running 3.5 beta (Galileo) without problems, though. And yeah... it can be a little slow at times to place the underline. I find there's no need to wait for the underline though. ctrl+click and wait a sec.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll try again some time. But I still need to move my hand to the mouse; somehow I'm more of a keyboard person when it comes to coding :) even though my coworkers always use Ctrl+Click

Comment: well if it reacts that slow it sounds to me that CPU should be used by eclipse cause of the "search" - but eclipse does nothing in my case
on my linux box 'top' shows that java does nothing and even after a minute it doesnt work
it doesnt work with Ctrl+left OR F3

which sounds like the option is turned off - anyone knows where this can be enabled/disabled?
and
does this function work for class methods too - cause thats what im trying to open like $this->somefunction();

Comment: In General > .... > Hyperlinking i have no entry for pdt and it seems there is no way to add it
hmm - could be that my installation is broken